Windows 10 / Ubuntu Dual boot goes to Grub if Ubuntu selected
I had Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed on 2 separate SSDs on my MSI laptop. I also had a bootable flash drive created with Ubuntu as bootable. When I was starting my laptop and hit F11 (MSI boot), it showed all three entries properly, and everything worked great.
At some point I decided to upgrade Ubuntu on SSD. This upgrade did not work (I can't remember the reason), and I decided to get rid of this installation.
After that Windows boots fine without pressing F11.
When F11 pressed I see Windows 10 and my USB Ubuntu as choices, but when I select Ubuntu, it goes to Grub.
I want to repair the bootloader somehow and continue using my USB. I created a boot info via boot repair from a LiveUSB.
I would appreciate if somebody can help to resolve this:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rJxGSQSyff/
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1 and looks at 
    sector 1 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be 
    found at this location.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => libparted MBR boot code is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, nvme1n1p1 
                       starts at sector 2048. But according to the info from 
                       fdisk, nvme1n1p1 starts at sector 63. According to the 
                       info in the boot sector, nvme1n1p1 has 1048576 
                       sectors.. But according to the info from the partition 
                       table, it has 2000407152 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sdb5
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: TU104M [GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER Mobile / Max-Q] CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] simpledrmdrmfb from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: E17E9IMS.10D(1.13) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000,0001
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,546bb5c7-6c16-4d77-916a-d2827bc57428,0x800,0x96000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000000000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,546bb5c7-6c16-4d77-916a-d2827bc57428,0x800,0x96000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x5774e177,0x800,0x3a977c0)0000424f

07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
1d43d986c265d8c455d020e4a1f28c52   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
1d260ff1255f189ab621209796ee2fed   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
1d260ff1255f189ab621209796ee2fed   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
13bbe79f47b4d57f791e51f5c01f7ac8   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
a7e895ae35e102411330a3e52636b457   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
4c75682f8c4ddf9ca2f68ba84c3bf240   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme1n1p1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme1n1p1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   nvme1n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
5c14b2158486ded02655f86386b249e2   nvme1n1p1/BOOT/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme1n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
04cd9cb6ceccbde1ca100ed1cae0f429   nvme1n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme1n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme1n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme1n1 : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme1n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme1n1p3   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme1n1p1   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme1n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdb5    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme1n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme1n1
nvme1n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme1n1
sdb5    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  fstab-has-goodBOOT, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb1    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme1n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xefc41648
         Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
nvme1n1p1         63 2000407215 2000407153 953.9G 42 SFS
Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 3FAEE4E5-B177-45AA-8F1C-7033ABBDE2EC
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048     616447     614400   300M EFI System
nvme0n1p2     616448     878591     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3     878592 1952677887 1951799296 930.7G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 1952677888 1954521087    1843200   900M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 1954521088 2000408575   45887488  21.9G Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x5774e177
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 61439935 61437888 29.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk sdb: 239.02 GiB, 256641603584 bytes, 501253132 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xbc46b8ce
     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1          2048   1953791   1951744   953M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdb2       1955838 501252095 499296258 238.1G  5 Extended
sdb5       1955840 501252095 499296256 238.1G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:31.5GB:31.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;
sdb:257GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Samsung Flash Drive:;
1:1049kB:1000MB:999MB:ext4::esp;
2:1001MB:257GB:256GB:::;
5:1001MB:257GB:256GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:WDC PC SN730 SDBPNTY-1T00-1032:;
1:1049kB:316MB:315MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
2:316MB:450MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
3:450MB:1000GB:999GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:1000GB:1001GB:944MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag, no_automount;
5:1001GB:1024GB:23.5GB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;
nvme1n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:msdos:SPCC M.2 PCIe SSD:;
1:32.3kB:1024GB:1024GB:::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      vfat     C0C5-F293                            5774e177-01                          UBUNTU 24_0 
sdb                                                                                                        
├─sdb1      ext4     a37ee441-5c5e-4bdb-9ecb-cdcaff6bb973 bc46b8ce-01                                      
├─sdb2                                                    bc46b8ce-02                                      
└─sdb5      ext4     e29c5575-a3cc-41aa-8301-cc357de2da3f bc46b8ce-05                                      
nvme1n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme1n1p1 vfat     ED2D-734B                                                                             
├─nvme1n1p2                                                                                                
└─nvme1n1p3 ntfs     2432439D3243733A                                                          Data        
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     D894-B1AF                            546bb5c7-6c16-4d77-916a-d2827bc57428 SYSTEM      EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               168cb3e9-77b9-4fde-807e-f765f58cf97e             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     948A953A8A951A36                     f24ee0f7-7e55-44be-b005-e821b6d2c645 Windows     Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     76DC95E9DC95A3C1                     78f48413-9213-4a6b-8be6-b087b5da7edf WinRE tools Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     926297CB6297B289                     814bfff7-0dc5-4c38-895b-fdbac832d2dc BIOS_RVY    Basic data partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1         264.1M  11% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3         400.8G  57% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4         270.8M  70% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5         754.5M  97% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme1n1p1         500.3M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p1
/dev/sda1               23.5G  20% /cdrom
/dev/sdb1              588.5M  29% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb5              200.3G   9% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb5
efivarfs               129.4K  30% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3         fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme1n1p1         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb1              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb5              ext4            rw,relatime

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid bd883108-4b88-4c77-8e17-38f8c2da2f5c root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme1n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid bd883108-4b88-4c77-8e17-38f8c2da2f5c root hd0,msdos5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

======================== sdb1/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

Ubuntu   e29c5575-a3cc-41aa-8301-cc357de2da3f
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (20.04) (on nvme0n1p5)   bd883108-4b88-4c77-8e17-38f8c2da2f5c
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme1n1p1)   osprober-efi-D894-B1AF
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.180679321 = 0.194002944    grub/grub.cfg                                  1
   0.178958893 = 0.192155648    vmlinuz                                        2
   0.280529022 = 0.301215744    vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic                       1
   0.178958893 = 0.192155648    vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic                       2
   0.280529022 = 0.301215744    vmlinuz.old                                    1
   0.490852356 = 0.527048704    initrd.img                                     5
   0.249645233 = 0.268054528    initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic                    1
   0.490852356 = 0.527048704    initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic                    5
   0.249645233 = 0.268054528    initrd.img.old                                 1

========================== sdb5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=e29c5575-a3cc-41aa-8301-cc357de2da3f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=a37ee441-5c5e-4bdb-9ecb-cdcaff6bb973 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme1n1p1 during installation
UUID=D894-B1AF  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

======================= sdb5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

===================== sdb5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Aug 21 18:39 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/nvme1n1p3 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p3 
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/nvme1n1p3 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p3 


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sdb5,
using the following options:  sdb1/boot nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

SFS detected. You may want to retry after converting Windows dynamic partitioning (SFS partitions) to a basic disk. This can be performed via tools such as TestDisk or EASEUS-Partition-Master / MiniTool-Partition-Wizard.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

